# LINQ to count items with no occurrences in other entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Lets say we have a *Domains* entity and a *Reports* entity, where reports are generated for selected domains.

```
Class Domain 
{ 
[key] 
int Id {get; set} 
string Domain {get; set}
}


Class Report
{
[key]
int Id {get; set} 
datetime Created {get; set}
int DomainId {get; set}
//etc.
}
```

I need to write a LINQ-to-Entities query that returns 2 int values: the amount of domains which have no reports, and the total count of reports, as in **"3 of 209 domains have no reports associated".** 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: does it need to be 1 query? If not you could just count all domains and then just do another count (distinct on DomainId) on the second table. If not just do your usual outer join.

Comment: Ideally one query, the two values would be returned as JSON array.

Comment: I think it should end with a `select` clause with anonymous types, something like `select new { DomainsWithNoReports = <something>, totalDomains = <somethingelse> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Domain` entity looks like it could do with a one-to-many relationship with `Report` entities, as follows:

```
public class Domain
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    public Domain()
    {
        Reports = new List<Report>();
    }
}
```

To get the number of domains with no reports you can then do something like the following:

```
var countOfDomainsWithNoReports = 
    context.Domains.Count(x => !x.Reports.Any());
```

Then to get both the total count and count with no reports **as a single query**:

```
var report = (from domains in context.Domains
    let totalDomains = context.Domains.Count()
    let domainsWithNoReports = context.Domains.Count(x => !x.Reports.Any())
    select new {totalDomains, domainsWithNoReports}).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the counts as an anonymous type with properties `totalDomains` and `domainsWithNoReports`.

Comment: The relationship exists, so yes, I'm going to try your solution. I wasn't aware of the `let` clause. Thank you LongboatHarry.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code herepublic class Domain 
{ 
    public int Id {get; set; } 
    public string Dom {get; set;}
}

public class Report
{

    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public DateTime Created {get; set;}
    public int DomainId { get; set; }

}


List<Domain> objDomain = new List<Domain>();
        List<Report> objReport = new List<Report>();

        Domain objD1 = new Domain();
        Report objR1 = new Report();

        objD1.Id = 1;
        objD1.Dom = "google.com";

        objR1.Id = 1;
        objR1.DomainId = 1;

        objDomain.Add(objD1);
        objReport.Add(objR1);

         Domain objD2 = new Domain();
        Report objR2 = new Report();

        objD2.Id = 2;
        objD2.Dom = "yahoo.com";

        objR2.Id = 2;
        objR2.DomainId = 1;

        objDomain.Add(objD2);
        objReport.Add(objR2);

 int count = objDomain.Count(Domaindata => objReport.Any(ReportData => ReportData.DomainId != Domaindata.Id));
```

Output is = 1

for more details check code in my save fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZhEj8Z

Answer (score 0):

With Except (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

I.e. 
     `var firstMinusSecond = first.Except(second);`

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes, there is an `Except` SQL operator.

Comment: really? Wow - impressive - and it can work with all kind of projections? On Server-Side? ... I think I have to look into this - thanks for the remark

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution but i tested on lists i don't know if it works on linq to entities. The query returns a Tuple of 2 integers. The first one is the total reports, the second one is the number of domains without reports.

```
var test = domains.Aggregate(new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0), (partial, next) =>
        {
            var domainReports = reports.Count(p => p.DomainId == next.Id);

            var ret = new Tuple<int, int>(partial.Item1 + domainReports, domainReports > 0 ? partial.Item2 + 1 : partial.Item2);
            return ret;
        });
```